# pandas.read_csv: how do I parse 2 sets of two columns as datetimes and name the parsed column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing, named

I can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(usage_output, parse_dates=[['StartDate', 'StartTime'],['EndDate', 'EndTime']])
```

I can also do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(usage_output, parse_dates={'TimeStamp_Start': ['StartDate', 'StartTime']})
```

How to combine both, so that I have two parsed columns "TimeStamp_Start" and "TimeStamp_End"?

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(usage_output, parse_dates=[{'TimeStamp_Start': ['StartDate', 'StartTime']}, {'TimeStamp_End': ['EndDate', 'EndTime']}])
```

**Error**

> ValueError: {'TimeStamp_Start': ['StartDate', 'StartTime']} is not in
> list

Comment: could you clarify: in your csv, you have date and time in separate columns and you want to combine them in one datetime column in the dataframe?

Comment: `parse_dates={'TimeStamp_Start': ['StartDate', 'StartTime'], 'TimeStamp_End': ['EndDate', 'EndTime']}`, just pass a dictionary, not a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Thx to shijith
df = pd.read_csv(usage_output, parse_dates={'TimeStamp_Start': ['StartDate', 'StartTime'], 'TimeStamp_End': ['EndDate', 'EndTime']})